# Can Thread.setContextClassLoader set a different ClassLoader than returned by getCCL?

Tags: java, classloader, contextclassloader

**Background:**

Recently I implemented a piece of code that would set the appropratie ClassLoader for a specific operation, and finally restore the original ClassLoader once the operation was completed.

For example:

```
ClassLoader originalCL = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(specialCL);
    // do operation here that requires 'specialCL'
} finally {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(originalCL);
}
```

According to the `getContextClassLoader()` doc, a null being returned could mean two things.  1) The system CL or 2) if getting the sys CL failed, the bootstrap CL.

> **returns:** the context ClassLoader for this Thread, *or null indicating the system class  loader (or, failing that, the bootstrap class loader)*

According to the `setContextClassLoader(Classloader cl)` doc, if a null CL is provided then either the 1) the system CL or 2) if setting the sys CL failed, the bootstrap CL.

> **cl** - the context ClassLoader for this Thread, *or null indicating the system class loader (or, failing that, the bootstrap class loader)*

---

**Question:**

Is it possible that using the above try-finally-restore programming model, I could end up with a different ClassLoader on the Thread than I originally started with?

For example:

```
// start out with System CL

ClassLoader original = getContextClassLoader(); // returns null

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(otherCL);

Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(original); // i.e. set to null
// setCCL() tries to set System CL... fails 
// setCCL() tries to set Bootstrap CL... succeeds
```

The reverse of this could also be true where we start out with the Bootstrap CL and when we try to restore using `setContextClassLoader(null)` the System CL gets restored.  Is either case possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when you set the context class loader to `null`, it is simply set to `null`. So it will continue using whatever class loader it had used initially.

Comment: Where is the reference to the initially used classloader stored?  In my examples I'm setting the ClassLoader to something else, and then trying to restore it

Comment: @aguibert In the OpenJDK implementation the `Thread` class simply has a field called [`contextClassLoader`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Thread.java?av=f).

Comment: the part I'm not clear on is how the failover mechanism works, when does that come into play?  Obviously setting a field to null would never fail, so why does the javadoc describe behavior for it?  If someone could describe why this mention of failover is in place, I would consider that a sufficient answer

Comment: @aguibert I think you may be misunderstanding the idiom "failing that". It simply means something like "if that isn't available", not actual failure of anything.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a legacy project and saw that in the Kafka configurations, the developer tried to set ContextClassLoader to null! by calling this `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(null);`. do you know why he did this? What are the situations in which we should set ContextClassLoader to null?